# Datatables Select All Checkbox

Tags: jquery, datatables

The demo on the select all doesn't really work. 
https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

What's the best way to implement the select all checkbox after they are created via the `columnDef` attributes?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
let example = $('#example').DataTable({
    columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 0
    }],
    select: {
        style: 'os',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    order: [
        [1, 'asc']
    ]
});
example.on("click", "th.select-checkbox", function() {
    if ($("th.select-checkbox").hasClass("selected")) {
        example.rows().deselect();
        $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        example.rows().select();
        $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }
}).on("select deselect", function() {
    ("Some selection or deselection going on")
    if (example.rows({
            selected: true
        }).count() !== example.rows().count()) {
        $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }
});
```

I've added to the CSS though:

```
table.dataTable tr th.select-checkbox.selected::after {
    content: "✔";
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgb(176, 190, 217) 1px 1px, rgb(176, 190, 217) -1px -1px, rgb(176, 190, 217) 1px -1px, rgb(176, 190, 217) -1px 1px;
}
```

Working [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/yxLrLr8o/), hope that helps.

Comment: And make sure to use DataTable and not dataTable for anyone else having problems.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/annoyingmouse/yxLrLr8o/ does not work with last 1.2.5 release of select.dataTables.css
Any clue to make it working ?

Comment: I've had a wee look at the css and it's changed a little, perhaps raise another question rather than adding a comment?

Comment: @annoyingmouse I am having the same problem... and even when the TH element has "select-checkbox" class, checkbox is not shown. What may be missing? There is some differences. First, I am getting data from Ajax, and the other, when seeing the rendered table, I can see 2 divs. One with class "dataTables_scrollHeadInner" and the other "dataTables_scrollBody". Both content has the same header row.

Comment: @annoyingmouse never mind... I think this is a bug in select plugin. Please see this post: https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/53372/bug-in-select-plugin-when-showing-checkboxes/p1. I have reported this bug and posted my solution based on yours.

Comment: The above solution is going to only work if in addition to above changes you also have the datatables 'select' extension included as well.

Comment: How can i catch click action on checkboxes? Like select all checkbox

Answer (score 28):

You can use [Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) extension for jQuery Datatables.

```
var table = $('#example').DataTable({
   'ajax': 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/1us28',
   'columnDefs': [
      {
         'targets': 0,
         'checkboxes': {
            'selectRow': true
         }
      }
   ],
   'select': {
      'style': 'multi'
   },
   'order': [[1, 'asc']]
});
```

See [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/snqw56dw/) for code and demonstration.

See [Checkboxes](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) project page for [more examples](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/examples/) and [documentation](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/reference/).

Comment: This is one splendid plugin for Datatables with well written API. I'd recommend it better than the first answer marked as "accepted"

Comment: Note this library has a line of code that stops propagation for the click event on the targeted checkboxes. So if you want to use the click event for targeted checkboxes, such as displaying a button on checkbox click, then either use another event like 'change', or create a custom event.

Comment: This only says `1 row selected` no matter how many rows I select or select all???? Also if I select one row it automatically select the select all.

Comment: FYI if using HTML (DOM) you MUST, MUST have a row index for each row, as in the first <td> is `<td>1<\td>` and not just a blank `<td><\td>`.  This is low hanging fruit things to mention in your documentation!! :)

Comment: @BrianWiley, it's mentioned in the documentation in the [Known Limitation](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) section, but nobody reads it, I guess.

Answer (score 13):

You can use **[this option](https://datatables.net/reference/button/selectAll) provided by [dataTable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/datatables) itself** using buttons.

```
dom: 'Bfrtip',
 buttons: [
      'selectAll',
      'selectNone'
 ]'
```

Here is a sample code

```
var tableFaculty = $('#tableFaculty').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        {
            data: function (row, type, set) {
                return '';
            }
        },
        {data: "NAME"}
    ],
    "columnDefs": [
        {
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0
        }
    ],
    select: {
        style: 'multi',
        selector: 'td:first-child'
    },
    dom: 'Bfrtip',
    buttons: [
        'selectAll',
        'selectNone'
    ],
    "order": [[0, 'desc']]
});
```

Answer (score 8):

I made a simple implementation of this functionality using fontawesome, also taking advantage of the Select Extension, this covers select all, deselect some items, deselect all. https://codepen.io/pakogn/pen/jJryLo

HTML:

```
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <button style="border: none; background: transparent; font-size: 14px;" id="MyTableCheckAllButton">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>  
                </button>
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Javascript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    let myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0,
        }],
        select: {
            style: 'os', // 'single', 'multi', 'os', 'multi+shift'
            selector: 'td:first-child',
        },
        order: [
            [1, 'asc'],
        ],
    });

    $('#MyTableCheckAllButton').click(function() {
        if (myTable.rows({
                selected: true
            }).count() > 0) {
            myTable.rows().deselect();
            return;
        }

        myTable.rows().select();
    });

    myTable.on('select deselect', function(e, dt, type, indexes) {
        if (type === 'row') {
            // We may use dt instead of myTable to have the freshest data.
            if (dt.rows().count() === dt.rows({
                    selected: true
                }).count()) {
                // Deselect all items button.
                $('#MyTableCheckAllButton i').attr('class', 'far fa-check-square');
                return;
            }

            if (dt.rows({
                    selected: true
                }).count() === 0) {
                // Select all items button.
                $('#MyTableCheckAllButton i').attr('class', 'far fa-square');
                return;
            }

            // Deselect some items button.
            $('#MyTableCheckAllButton i').attr('class', 'far fa-minus-square');
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I tried all the answers here, and a number from other places online. This was the only solution which (a) properly kept the state of the checkboxes on each row in sync with the selected state of the row; (b) provided the correct indeterminate state in the header; and (c) maintained correct state even when filters were applied to the table. Bravo!

Comment: Thanks for your solution. For those thinking how to progamatically add a button in the header of the first column this is how (using `<span>` instead of `<i>`): `$(myTable.column(0).header()).html("<button type='button' style='...' id='MyTableCheckAllButton'><span class='fa-regular fa-square'></span></button>");`

Answer (score 1):

[The solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42580076/11243582) given by [@annoyingmouse](https://stackoverflow.com/users/592058/annoyingmouse) works for me.

But to use the checkbox in the header cell, I also had to fix [select.dataTables.css](https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.3.1/css/select.dataTables.css).
It seems that they used :

> table.dataTable **tbody** th.select-checkbox

instead of :

> table.dataTable **thead** th.select-checkbox

So I had to add this to my css :

```
table.dataTable thead th.select-checkbox {
  position: relative;
}
table.dataTable thead th.select-checkbox:before,
table.dataTable thead th.select-checkbox:after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  top: 1.2em;
  left: 50%;
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
table.dataTable tbody td.select-checkbox:before,
table.dataTable thead th.select-checkbox:before {
  content: ' ';
  margin-top: -6px;
  margin-left: -6px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 3px;
}
```

Comment: I am going through the same situation. I am using table-sm css class and it is causing issues with header alignment. Did you use table-sm ?

Comment: No, I don't use table-sm.

Answer (score 0):

Base on [Francisco Daniel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4231380/francisco-daniel)'s answer I modified some of the Jquery code here's My version. I removed some excess code and use "fa" instead of "far" for the icon. I also remove the "far fa-minus-square" since I can't understand its purpose.

-- Edited --

I added the "draw" event for the button icon to update whenever the table is redrawn or reloaded. Because I noticed when I tried to reload the table using "myTable.ajax.reload()" the button icon is not changing.

https://codepen.io/john-kenneth-larbo/pen/zXeYpz

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    let myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
        columnDefs: [{
            orderable: false,
            className: 'select-checkbox',
            targets: 0,
        }],
        select: {
            style: 'os', // 'single', 'multi', 'os', 'multi+shift'
            selector: 'td:first-child',
        },
        order: [
            [1, 'asc'],
        ],
    });

       myTable.on('select deselect draw', function () {
        var all = myTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).count(); // get total count of rows
        var selectedRows = myTable.rows({ selected: true, search: 'applied' }).count(); // get total count of selected rows

        if (selectedRows < all) {
            $('#MyTableCheckAllButton i').attr('class', 'fa fa-square-o');
        } else {
            $('#MyTableCheckAllButton i').attr('class', 'fa fa-check-square-o');
        }

    });

    $('#MyTableCheckAllButton').click(function () {
        var all = myTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).count(); // get total count of rows
        var selectedRows = myTable.rows({ selected: true, search: 'applied' }).count(); // get total count of selected rows


        if (selectedRows < all) {
            //Added search applied in case user wants the search items will be selected
            myTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).deselect();
            myTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).select();
        } else {
            myTable.rows({ search: 'applied' }).deselect();
        }
    });
});
```

```html
<table id="example" class="display" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                <button style="border: none; background: transparent; font-size: 14px;" id="MyTableCheckAllButton">
                <i class="far fa-square"></i>  
                </button>
            </th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Tiger Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Garrett Winters</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>63</td>
            <td>$170,750</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Ashton Cox</td>
            <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>66</td>
            <td>$86,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
            <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>22</td>
            <td>$433,060</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Airi Satou</td>
            <td>Accountant</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>33</td>
            <td>$162,700</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Brielle Williamson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>$372,000</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Herrod Chandler</td>
            <td>Sales Assistant</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>59</td>
            <td>$137,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Rhona Davidson</td>
            <td>Integration Specialist</td>
            <td>Tokyo</td>
            <td>55</td>
            <td>$327,900</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Colleen Hurst</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>39</td>
            <td>$205,500</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Sonya Frost</td>
            <td>Software Engineer</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>23</td>
            <td>$103,600</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>Jena Gaines</td>
            <td>Office Manager</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>$90,560</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
    <tfoot>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
        </tr>
    </tfoot>
</table>
```

Comment: The fa-minus-square glyph is how you show the [indeterminate state](https://css-tricks.com/indeterminate-checkboxes/), also called "[mixed state](https://developer.apple.com/design/human-interface-guidelines/macos/buttons/checkboxes/)". It's a common state for checkboxes, and makes particular sense in a select all checkbox for a set of table rows. Cf. [Gmail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2CkVK.png).