# I am using data-table for listing, i added checkbox column for select-all, but jquery not working only for those checkboxes

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using data-table for listing.. everything working properly.. but now i have added checkbox-columns for select-all functionality..

But problem is that.. jquery working everywhere on that page.. but jquery only not working for those checkboxes

My Code Snippet:
.....

```
<tr>
  <th>
    <input type="checkbox" name="confirmselectall" id="confirmselectall" />
  </th>
  .......
</tr>
.....
.....
<tr class="odd gradeX">
  <td>
    <input name="confirm[]" id="confirm" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row -> order_id; ?>" class="confirm">
  </td>
  .........
</tr>
```

My jquery script:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#confirmselectall").click(function () { 
                $(".confirm").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            });

            $(".confirm").change(function(){ 
                if (!$(this).prop("checked")){
                    $("#confirmselectall").prop("checked",false);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

simple alert(); also not working.. why jquery not working only for checkboxes.. on same page.. jquery working properly for those functionalities.. please suggest me changes??

Comment: I think your approach is not the good one, let's do DataTable manage checkboxes itself... maybe this will help you : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570465/datatables-select-all-checkbox

Comment: yes i am using this script after $('#mytable').DataTable(); though its not working

Comment: Please provide me your DataTable code.

Answer (score 0):

because input checkbox not ready when document ready . you must use on.('click') instead of click

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css"/>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/css/select.dataTables.min.css"/>
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.15/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
 <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/select/1.2.2/js/dataTables.select.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    var info = $('#example').DataTable( {

        order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
    } );

 $('#checkall').click(function () {
        $(':checkbox', info.rows().nodes()).prop('checked', this.checked);
    });
} );
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table id="example" class="display" cellspacing="0" width="100%">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><input type="checkbox" id="checkall" title="Select all" onClick="toggle(this)"/></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tfoot>
            <tr>
                <th></th>
                <th>Name</th>
                <th>Position</th>
                <th>Office</th>
                <th>Age</th>
                <th>Salary</th>
            </tr>
        </tfoot>
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="confirm[]" type="checkbox" value="2323" class="confirm"></td>
                <td>Garrett Winters</td>
                <td>Accountant</td>
                <td>Tokyo</td>
                <td>63</td>
                <td>$170,750</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="confirm[]" type="checkbox" value="2324" class="confirm"></td>
                <td>Ashton Cox</td>
                <td>Junior Technical Author</td>
                <td>San Francisco</td>
                <td>66</td>
                <td>$86,000</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td><input name="confirm[]" type="checkbox" value="2224" class="confirm"></td>
                <td>Cedric Kelly</td>
                <td>Senior Javascript Developer</td>
                <td>Edinburgh</td>
                <td>22</td>
                <td>$433,060</td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: other jquery functionalities working properly.. only problem is for checkboxes of select-all

Comment: You said simple alert not working. could be js conflict.. what's the error you find in js error console?

Answer (score 0):

Straight from documentation

*A page can't be manipulated safely until the document is "ready." jQuery detects this state of readiness for you. Code included inside `$( document ).ready()` will only run once the page Document Object Model (DOM) is ready for JavaScript code to execute. Code included inside `$( window ).on( "load", function() { ... })` will run once the entire page (images or iframes), not just the DOM, is ready.*

Look here for more info 
https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

In your case make sure your DOM is ready.

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr>
  <th>
    <input type="checkbox" name="confirmselectall" id="confirmselectall" />
  </th>
  .......
</tr>
.....
.....
<tr class="odd gradeX">
  <td>
    <input name="confirm[]" id="confirm" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row -> order_id; ?>" class="confirm">
    <input name="confirm[]" id="confirm" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row -> order_id; ?>" class="confirm">
    <input name="confirm[]" id="confirm" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row -> order_id; ?>" class="confirm">
    <input name="confirm[]" id="confirm" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row -> order_id; ?>" class="confirm">
    <input name="confirm[]" id="confirm" type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row -> order_id; ?>" class="confirm">
  </td>
  .........
</tr>
</table>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#confirmselectall").on('click',function () { 
             console.log('checked');
                $(".confirm").prop('checked', $(this).prop('checked'));
            });

            $(".confirm").change(function(){ 
                if (!$(this).prop("checked")){
                    $("#confirmselectall").prop("checked",false);
                }
            });
    });
</script>
```

For `DataTable` have a look at the following

https://jsfiddle.net/gyrocode/07Lrpqm7/

Comment: if i use min.js directly in view file then it works.. but other jquery functoinalities stops working..

Comment: check you dev console for error. It might not be jquery itself

Comment: I have added datatable fiddle have a look at it. Hope it might help you.

Answer (score 0):

I know its too late to answer my own question, though I am answering for helping purpose, without caring points..

For data tables, I was facing issue with checkboxes column.

Only for those checkboxes, jQuery issue was there

even alert() was not working, but many searches.. I got solution

```
$("input[name=field_name]").on('ifChecked', function (event) {
      ......
      ......
});
```

there is special event for checkboxes & data-tables combination, "ifChecked"

now jquery working propelry..