# How to add select all check box in data table?

Tags: angular, angular6

can anyone explain how to add checkbox for data table? Like I developed an existing code which displays all dynamic data from response and now I want to add check box against it.

Answer (score 0):

When you are initializing the data table object you can include the select property to introduce a checkbox column.

`select: {
    style:    'os',
    selector: 'td:first-child'
}`

Full details can be found on the Datatables website: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/initialisation/checkbox.html

If you are looking for a way to select every row in the table at once there are some good solutions in this post: [Datatables Select All Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570465/datatables-select-all-checkbox)

Hope this helps and is what you are looking for!