# datatable select all checkbox

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, datatable

I am trying to create a datatable with a 'select all' feature that will select every row. I have a WIP jsfiddle with a checkbox you can use to select each row, and I created a checkbox column header that I am trying to make so when you click it, it selects all rows, and if you de-select a row, the select-all box turns unchecked.

I'm trying to replicate the functionality found in this answer: [Datatables Select All Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570465/datatables-select-all-checkbox/49668175)

I have my code in a jsfiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/martinradio/a9bjtLkr/62/

I create my datatable with js / html /css like so, and I added in the solution from the other linked question, but my jsfiddle datatable still will not select all ?

```js
$(document).ready(function () {

let dataset = [
  ["<input type='checkbox'>", "img1", "23443", "a"],
  ["<input type='checkbox'>", "img2", "999", "b"],
  ["<input type='checkbox'>", "img3", "777", "z"],
  ["<input type='checkbox'>", "img2", "999", "b"],
  ["<input type='checkbox'>", "img3", "777", "z"],
 ]

let myProductGapsTable = $('#myProductGapsTable').DataTable({
      retrieve: true,
      scrollY: "60vh", 
      scrollX: true,
      scrollCollapse: true,
      paging: false,
      "autoWidth": true,
      data: dataset,
      //"sDom": 'tib',
      select: {
          //style: 'multi',
          style: 'os',
            selector: 'td:first-child',
          search: 'applied',
      },
      buttons: [ {
                        extend: 'excelHtml5',
                        text: 'excel_selected',
                        exportOptions: { rows: { selected: true, search: 'applied' } }

                    }, ],
     columnDefs: [{
        orderable: false,
        className: 'select-checkbox',
        targets: 0
    }],
  });
  
  myProductGapsTable.on("click", "th.select-checkbox", function() {
    if ($("th.select-checkbox").hasClass("selected")) {
        myProductGapsTable.rows().deselect();
        $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        myProductGapsTable.rows().select();
        $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }
}).on("select deselect", function() {
    ("Some selection or deselection going on")
    if (myProductGapsTable.rows({
            selected: true
        }).count() !== myProductGapsTable.rows().count()) {
        $("th.select-checkbox").removeClass("selected");
    } else {
        $("th.select-checkbox").addClass("selected");
    }
});

  //use custom export excel button
  $('#exportExcelProductGaps').click(function () {
      myProductGapsTable.button(0).trigger()
  });

  
  })
```

```css
table.dataTable tr th.select-checkbox.selected::after {
    content: "✔";
    margin-top: -11px;
    margin-left: -4px;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: rgb(176, 190, 217) 1px 1px, rgb(176, 190, 217) -1px -1px, rgb(176, 190, 217) 1px -1px, rgb(176, 190, 217) -1px 1px;
}
```

```html
<button id='exportExcelProductGaps'>
download excel
</button>
<div id='myProductGapsTableContainer' class="table-responsive">
      <table class="table table-sm card-table" id='myProductGapsTable' class="display" width="100%">
          <thead>
              <tr>
                  <th><input id='selectAllProductGaps' type="checkbox"></th> 
                  <th><a href="javascript:;" class="text-muted sort" >Img</a></th>
                  <th><a href="javascript:;" class="text-muted sort" data-sort="UPC">UPC / SKU</a></th>
                  <th><a href="javascript:;" class="text-muted sort" data-sort="Parent SKU">Parent SKU</a></th>
              </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody class="list">
          </tbody>
      </table>
  </div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29896599/how-can-i-select-all-checkboxes-from-all-the-pages-in-a-jquery-datatable

Comment: @noobprogrammer it helps thanks, I updated my current issue here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62670339/datatable-cant-programatically-select-row