# datatable cant programatically select row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable

I have a datatable with a working system to select rows, if you click anywhere in the row (not just the checkbox), it will select the row (greying it out) and check the box, it also tracks the number of selected rows in the bottom info text.
[image]

I'm trying to get the first column header 'select all' checkbox to correctly select all rows, this function detects when the select all button is pressed:

```
        //select all
        $('body').on('click', '#productGapsSelectAll', function () {
            var allPages = myProductGapsTable.rows().nodes();
            console.log("allPages.length = ", allPages.length, ", allPages = ", allPages)
            
            myProductGapsTable.rows().every(function(rowIdx, tableLoop, rowLoop){
                var node=this.node();
                console.log(`${rowIdx} selected = ${$(node).hasClass('selected')}`);
                $(node).toggleClass('selected');
                //$(node).click()
                //$(node).select();
            });
}
```

When I use `$(node).toggleClass('selected')` it only greys out the box, and doesnt check the checkbox,

[image]

`$(node).click()` and `$(node).select();` dont check the box or grey the row. Is there some way using `$(this)` that I can replicate the action of clicking on the row to select it?

EDIT

I can access the checkbox via Node, although no defining ID
[image]

edit2; tried getting checkbox value from node but there is no 'checked' string inside the input element

[image]

Comment: If you can find the checkbox below `$(node)` you can set it's `checked` prop to `true`

Comment: updated post with image of what printing out node shows, im trying to access the first element

Comment: updated again, I got the checkbox input element but it doesnt reflect if the box is checked or not

Comment: It looks like you probably have multiple checkboxes with the same `id`? That's not valid HTML.

Comment: DONT GO THIS WAY. Are you using `select` with datatables? If not, plase go here: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/ . If you have any cuestion tell me with @ and i will help you

Comment: @Dani thanks, im trying to use this add on now. I added the scripts and `select:true` to my datatable initialization. my select all  button still has the same id, would you recommend adding a click listener for my selectAll button, then running some code to select all rows ? or is there some better way

Comment: @Martin if you are using select extension see this code, datatables has functions for select all and deselect: https://datatables.net/extensions/select/examples/api/select.html