# Datatable JS selectAll Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatable, datatables

Is there any event on Select - All checkbox for below Datatable.js example? to determine if it is selected or not.

[Datatables Select All Checkbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42570465/datatables-select-all-checkbox)

So I can set my global variable lets say

`var checkAll = 0;`

to

`checkAll = 1;`

I am trying to search for the same on Datatable website not getting solutions for the same.

Any help or guidance will be great!

Thanks.

Comment: cant find any event on this, but you can set value of checkAll but checking selected rows length with count of rows. table.rows({selected: true}).indexes().length

Comment: Thanks @shubham, will try and confirm here, if that works out.